# How do I have print-size content flow into new divs like Google Docs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So one thing that's really gotten my interest is Google Docs, not only does it create divs that look and function like pages (the appearance and layout of the div exactly matches how it will print) but it also opens creates a new one when one of the "pages" overflows.

I know of CSS Regions but I doubt they do that since browser support is almost nil without browser flags being turned on. On top of that how on earth do they pull off pixel perfect layout onto a real page when printed.

I'm not designing an editor or anything I'm just creating an html book but I want this book to give the illusion of pages on the monitor that when printed print exactly like the pages on the monitor. I also want the book to dynamically create new pages as content fills.

I'm familiar with CSS page breaks but that only applies to when printing, not visual appearance, and the divs still have to match up to the page size or weird overflows still happen upon print.